# Generar IPA para iOS en xamarin forms de visual studio 2017 desde windows

Tags: visual-studio, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

veréis tengo un proyecto en xamarin forms desarrollado en visual studio 2017, el objetivo es que sea multiplataforma. Para las pruebas de depurar y demás utilizo un móvil android conectado por cable al PC, windows 10 para las pruebas de UWP y una maquina virtual con MAC para la ejecución de un emulador de iOS y de este modo ver si funciona la app en iphone o ipad.

El siguiente paso es el de generar la aplicación para poder instalarla y probarla en dispositivos externos, para android y windows no tengo ningun problema, genero la app para su distribución ad hoc en android o el instalador de windows y todo sin problemas. El problema viene cuando intento generar el fichero .IPA para su instalación en un ipad.

No se muy bien los pasos a seguir para generar ese instalador, en principio según lo que estuve viendo por internet, creo los certificados en la web de desarrollo de apple, comienzo por un certificado de producción, a continuación creo el de la aplicación y el dispositivo con su guid y para finalizar genero el de distribución indicando el perfil y el dispositivo. Una vez hecho esto, voy a visual studio e intento ponerle configuracion ad-hoc que es la que te permite generar el fichero .IPA en el ordenador, y en teoría lo único que hace falta es compilar (poniendo la configuracion ad-hoc y como dispositivo pondria iphone en este caso y no iphonesimulator) , pero me da diferentes errores según la configuración que ponga. El más común de todos ellos es el siguiente:

[image: Error al compilar]

A ver si alguien sabe algo más a cerca de este procedimiento para la generación del instalador para iOS.

Comment: Sigo con el problema sin lograr resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

IOS es bastante especialito en cuanto a pruebas y despligue. Yo, con Xamarin y desde windows, nunca he desplegado Ad Hoc, siempre he lanzado a dispositivos que tenia conectados (en el mac) o a emuladores. Si te sirve lo que yo si que he hecho para obtener el IPA es, en propiedades del proyecto de iOS en la quinta opción (iOS IPA Options) marcar el check (Build iTunes PAckage Archive (IPA)), de esa manera cuando haces la compilación, en la carpeta de build correspondiente, junto a todos los archivos que necesita, genera el IPA (debug, o release o lo que sea.

Por si te sirve mi experiencia. Como has comentado tienes que tener en el portal de desarrollo de iOS creada la aplicación y generados los certificados, si vas a lanzar en dispositivos en pruebas tienes que haber añadido las ids de los dispositivos a esa aplicación.

Despues Xcode tiene que saber quien es el desarrollador, ya sea añadiendo la cuenta de usuario o añadiendo el certificado, de manera que en propiedades del proyecto iOS en visual studio, en la 4 sección (iOS Bundle Signing) te tiene que dejar elegir las dos primeras, en la primera el desarrollador y en la segunda el proyecto.

Si todo eso esta correcto entiendo que, igual como te deja probar, debe dejarte compilar Ad Hoc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, que ya es algo. En principio esos pasos que comentas son los que hago pero por desgracia me da el error que ves en la pregunta. Logre algo aunque creo que no es lo que necesito, me dejo compilar como Debug y Iphone, y ahí me genera un IPA, pero hasta la próxima semana no podre ver si ese ipa que genera es util, aunque creo que al ser con el método de debug no me servirá. Por todo lo que leí, en principio el metodo es adhoc, que es el método de pruebas, da igual que ponga adhoc o release que el resultado es el mismo

Comment: el error que mostré en la pregunta. No se si este proyecto xamarin forms para las 3 plataformas(ios, android y UWP) lo puedo migrar de algún modo a un mac (maquina virtual o físico) y crear el ipa desde allí

Comment: Vale, no mire el error, te pido disculpas, ahora que lo he mirado y googleado un poco parece que es un problema validación o algo referente a la ruta en accesoServicioDef, mira a ver si este post te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100006/sgen-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception-from-hresult-0x801314

Comment: Tengo una duda, yo también quiero generar un ipa, hice los mismos pasos peroooo cuando genero el ipa y lo paso a un dispositivo me marca error al instalar y si quiero desinstalar la aplicación me dice "Cancelar descarga", ¿será por que mi cuenta no pertenece al Apple Developer Program? (El pago que se debe hacer para inscribirse en el programa)